# In Fisher Exact test, why the more data you have, the more pvalue drops to smaller values?

Tags: p-value, fishers-exact-test

Suppose I have a contigency table

```
 18    2
  3   40
```

If I collect more data, it is likely that I obtain a matrix like this

```
180    20
 30   400
```

The pvalue drops from 9*10e-11 to 5*10e-100.

By intuition, I think this is because, the more data you collect, there are less chances to see differences in distribution with the same odds ratio.

Comment: If you have a large enough sample size, even the smallest difference in distributions will appear as significant. This is for every test, not only Fisher's exact test.

Comment: As far as I understand it, in Permutation tests, like Fisher's Exact tests, the precision of *p* is bound by the number of permutations. Think about it - the *p* value amounts to "[result] out of [*n* of possible results/all permutations]".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if you obtain 10x more data you will only multiply the number of points in each table entry (/group) by 10 *if and only if* the original table was already representative of the underlying ratios present in the population -- which in principle you could only get with big numbers. The lower the number of points, the stronger the impact of fluctuations in the counting.

The p-value is the probability of observing an effect as strong as the one we have observed (or even more extreme) *if* the null hypothesis is true. In our case the null hypothesis is that the properties represented in the table entries are not correlated. Fisher's exact test p-value just reflects that for very high numbers any difference in table entries is significant and should not arise out of statistical fluctuation.

Comment: "The p-value is just the probability of rejecting the null hypothesis by "accident"" what does this mean? It reads more like the definition of alpha/the Type I error rate. I don't think it's congruent with the meaning of a p value (which is the probability of the result conditional on H0).
Also you seem to miss that the question is not about whether p < alpha (significant), but why the already-low p decreases.

Comment: @jona you are correct, I will edit my answer.